# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hiredis' in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I'm using **async-redis** in node js when I want to build the **webpack** its giving me this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/redis-parser/lib/hiredis.js Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'hiredis' in '..../node_modules/redis-parser/lib

and when I try to install **hredis** it gives me this error:

> gyp ERR! build error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-
> gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
> gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-70-generic
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node"
> "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd
> /home/hezha/Desktop/api_node_js/stream_api_v2/node_modules/hiredis
> gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! hiredis@0.5.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the hiredis@0.5.0 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional  logging output above.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and this is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/server.ts"],
  output: {
    filename: "api.bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.json/, loader: "json-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
  },
  target: "node",
  node: {
    __dirname: true,
  },
  mode: "production",

  plugins: [],
};
```

and this is the version I'm using:

```
"ts-node": "^7.0.1",
"typescript": "^3.2.1",
"webpack": "^4.43.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
```

I really want to understand what is going on here, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to look next. Any suggestions?